# How to get data from SocketTCP to save to dataframe in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

> I try to get data from Socket TCP to append to dataframe I recived
> data and executed them to Seq() but when I using forEach to append
> them to dataframe has an problem This is my Code :

```
object CustomReceiver {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

    // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[2]")
      .appName("CustomReceiver")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    import spark.implicits._

   /*formatdata line data from Socket:  number1, 20210621090303, RadiusMessage, Stop, 84602496347, v241.66.85.130 */

    val linesData1 = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver("localhost", 11000))
    linesData1.flatMap(_.split(" ").map(_.trim))
    linesData1.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.foreach{ line => {

        val  arrraLine = line.split(",").toList
       // oke arrayLine data : List(number1, 20210621090303, RadiusMessage, Stop, 84602496347, 241.66.85.130)
        val testRDD = Seq(arrraLine).map(x =>(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)))
        // oke TestRDD : testRDD :List((number1,20210621090303,RadiusMessage,Stop,84602496347))

          val testDF = testRDD.toDF("cot1","cot2","cot3","cot4","cot5")
         // has an Problem
          testDF.show()
      }
      }
    }
       ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
      }
    }
```

This is my problem when running

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.localSeqToDatasetHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:231)
> at Cl.CustomReceiver$.$anonfun$main$4(CustomeReceiver.scala:52)
> at Cl.CustomReceiver$.$anonfun$main$4$adapted(CustomeReceiver.scala:45)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
> at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.foreach(CompletionIterator.scala:25)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$2(RDD.scala:1012)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1012)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do it is not very recommendable. If you want to work with Dataframes use Spark Structured Streaming. You are trying to create a DF inside a foreach RDD action. If you use the old Spark Streaming version go for RDDs.

You can create a DF inside the "foreachRDD" that creates a RDD for each mini-batch, but it is not a good idea. If you do the test you will see a lot of spark stages to create the new DF, and that for each mini-batch... With Structured Streaming you create directly the dataframe.